# Memory/Performance analysis tools for Android

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, profiling

I am new to Android. Can the standard Java Memory and performance analysis tools be used with Android?

For e.g. Can we create a heapdump file and analyse the Android app? Or Use Eclipse TPTP to analyse the memory/performance?

If its not possible to use standard Java tools for this purpose then is there any Android specific tools for Memory and performance analysis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, DDMS should help you do most of what you need.

[DDMS - Tracking memory allocation of objects](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc)

> DDMS provides a feature to track objects that are being allocated to
>   memory and to see which classes and threads are allocating the
>   objects. This allows you to track, in real time, where objects are
>   being allocated when you perform certain actions in your application.
>   This information is valuable for assessing memory usage that can
>   affect application performance.
>
> To track memory allocation of objects:
>
> In the Devices tab, select the process that you want to enable
>   allocation tracking for. In the Allocation Tracker tab, click the
>   Start Tracking button to begin allocation tracking. At this point,
>   anything you do in your application will be tracked. Click Get
>   Allocations to see a list of objects that have been allocated since
>   you clicked on the Start Tracking button. You can click on Get
>   Allocations again to append to the list new objects that that have
>   been allocated. To stop tracking or to clear the data and start over,
>   click the Stop Tracking button. Click on a specific row in the list to
>   see more detailed information such as the method and line number of
>   the code that allocated the object.

Comment: Additionally, if you do mobile web development you may find the Chrome remote debugger useful. https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

Comment: It appears that we cannot use standard Java tools for memory analysis, so as you pointed out DDMS can be used. http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Answer (score 2):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) can read Android heap dumps directly, without the need to convert them to the JSE format.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Answer (score 1):

There are existing performance profile tools on market.

General purposed tool, such as, SystemPanel app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1&hl=en. It lists the performance such as CPU, memory and network.

Professional tool, such as, TaskSpy - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skstudio.tooldelux. It lists system wide performance and enables you to profile one specific running process. What makes it really useful is that it enables you to 
see the performance from a remote PC/mac/linux computer, while the target test app can still run foreground on your phone/tablet - it is non-disruptive.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use standard Java tools directly. However if we create a Heapdump from Android app, and after converting it to Java SE HPROF format we can use Eclipse memory Analyzer to analyze memory.

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html